# Incremental (on-line) Backpropagation stopping criteria

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

In an on-line implementation of a Backpropagation ANN, how would you determine the stopping criteria?

The way that I have been doing it(which I am sure is incorrect) is to average the error of each output node and then average this error over each epoch.

Is this an incorrect method? Is there a standard way of stopping an on-line implementation?

Comment: It seems ok. Stop learning when your error on validation set is minimal (that is it starts to grow).

Comment: @Stan sorry,  I meant the average of my output node errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always consider the error (e.g. Root Mean Squared Error) on a validation set which is disjunct from your training set. If you train too long, your neural network will begin to *overfit*. This means, that the error on your training set will become minimal or even 0, but the error on general data will become worse.

To end up with the model parameters which yielded the best generalization performance, you should copy&save your model parameters whenever the error on your validation set is a new minimum. If performance is a problem, you can do this check only every N steps.

In an on-line learning setup, you will train with single training samples or mini-batches of a small number of training samples. You can consider the succsessive training of all samples/mini-batches that cover your total data as one *training epoch*.

There are several possibilities to define a so called *Early Stopping Criterion*. E.g. you could consider the best-so-far RMS Error on your validation set after each full epoch. You would stop as soon as there has not been a new optimum for M epochs. Depending on the complexity of your problem you must choose M high enough. You can also start with a rather small M and whenever you get a new optimum, you set M to the number of epochs you needed to reach it. It depends on whether it is more important to quickly converge or to be as thorough as possible.

You will always have situations where both your validation and/or training error will get bigger temporarily, because the learning algorithm is *hill-climbing*. This means it traverses regions on the error surface which render bad performance, but must be passed to reach a new, better optimum. If you simply stop as soon your validation or training error gets worse between two subsequent steps, you will end up in suboptimal solutions prematurely.